# how to find xpath of an element skipping the inner elements

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I have a complex html structure with lot of tables and divs.. and also the structure might change. How to find xpath by skipping the elements in between.
for example :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>First Name</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div>
                  <table>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <img src="1401-2ATd8" alt="" align="middle">
                        </td>
                        <td><span><input atabindex="2"  id=
                        "MainLimitLimit" type="text"></span></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have to get the input element with respect to the "First Name" span

eg :

```
By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'First Name')]/../../td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input")
```

but.. can I skip the between htmls and directly access the input element.. something like?

```
By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'First Name')]/../../td[2]//input[contains@id,'MainLimitLimit')]")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this Xpath :

```
//td[contains(span,'First Name')]/following-sibling::td[1]//input[contains(@id, 'MainLimitLimit')]
```

**Explanation :**

select `<td><span>First Name</span></td>` element :

```
//td[contains(span,'First Name')]
```

then get `<td>` element next to above `<td>` element :

```
/following-sibling::td[1]
```

then get `<input>` element within `<td>` element selected in the 2nd step above :

```
//input[contains(@id, 'MainLimitLimit')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `//` which means at any level

```
By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'First Name')]//td[2]/input[contains@id,'MainLimitLimit')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "First Name" span as a predicate. Try the code below

```
//td[preceding-sibling::td[span[contains(text(), 'First Name')]]]//input[contains(@id,'MainLimitLimit')]
```